# User limitation on Postgresql synthetic monitoring using Airflow

Tags: postgresql, permissions, ssl-certificate, airflow, monitoring

I am trying to write a synthetic monitoring for my on-prem postgresql service, using airflow. The monitoring should return if a cluster is available for creating tables, writing and reading data, and deleting tables.

The clusters on my service are using SSL certificates for authentication, which means a client is required to provide a suitable client certificate in order to connect to the cluster.

Currently, I have implemented my monitoring by creating a global user which will have a certificate with permissions to all the cluster. The user will have permissions to create, write and read only on one schema, dedicated to this monitoring. Using airflow, I will connect with this user each of my postgresql clusters and try to create a table, write to it, read, and then delete it. If one of the actions fails - the DAG will write a log describing the reason for failure.

My main problem with this solution it not being able to limit such a powerful user with accessibility to all of my clusters. In case an intruder will get the user's client certificate, he would be able to explode the DB storage by writing huge amount of data or overload queries and fail the cluster.

I am looking for some ideas for limiting this user so it will be able to act only for it's purpose- the simple actions required for this monitoring, and could not be exploit by an attacker. Alternatively, I would appreciate any suggestions for different implementation for this monitoring.

I searched for build in postgresql configurations that will allow me to limit the dedicated monitoring schema / limiting the amount of queries performed by the user.

Comment: We should all be so lucky, to have intruders announce their presence so blatantly and so (relatively) harmlessly.